# Hausman test in WORD in R

Tags: r, ms-word, stargazer

I want to transform the Hausman tests results into html so I can use them in my paper.

The following code is not working.

Do you have any ideas why?

```
    Hausman <-  phtest(MOD.FE.TIME, MOD.RANDOM)
    
    
    stargazer(Hausman, title = "Hausman Test", style = "default", decimal.mark = ",",
              out = "Hausmann.html")
```

The error given by R is:

```
% Error: Unrecognized object type.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simply that `phtest` models are not supported by stargazer.

According to [stargazer_models](https://rdrr.io/github/ChandlerLutz/stargazer/man/stargazer_models.html) the models supported from the `plm` package are `pgmm`, `plm` and `pmg`.

Comment: I see, is there any way to get the results with another package?

Comment: The `tidy` function in the `broom` package will extract the model results into a data frame, then you could use `kable` to display a table.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plm)
data("Gasoline", package = "plm")
form <- lgaspcar ~ lincomep + lrpmg + lcarpcap
wi <- plm(form, data = Gasoline, model = "within")
re <- plm(form, data = Gasoline, model = "random")
phtest(wi, re) -> my_ph_test
```

Stargazer can print any data frame into html or latex if you just set summary=FALSE. You can transform the phtest object into a data frame by broom::tidy().

```
library(broom)
tidy(my_ph_test) -> my_ph_test
```

Unfortunately, phtest object has some incompatibilities with tidy, so you need to manually transform the numeric vectors into numbers

```
my_ph_test$statistic <- round(as.numeric(my_ph_test$statistic),3)
my_ph_test$p.value <- round(as.numeric(my_ph_test$p.value),3)
my_ph_test$parameter <- as.numeric(my_ph_test$parameter)
```

You might also want to rename your columns to make them more descriptive:

```
names(my_ph_test)[1:3] <- c('Chisq', 'P-value','df')
```

Finally, generate the table
library(stargazer)
stargazer(my_ph_test, summary=FALSE, type='html')

Output:

```html
<table style="text-align:center"><tr><td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left"></td><td>Chisq</td><td>P-value</td><td>df</td><td>method</td><td>alternative</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr><tr><td style="text-align:left">1</td><td>302.804</td><td>0</td><td>3</td><td>Hausman Test</td><td>one model is inconsistent</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="6" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black"></td></tr></table>
```